# How to control moisture in home?

Tags: moisture, humidity

I shifted to my new flat recently. 
I found that it's quite moist inside, due to new construction.

Any one have any idea how I can control humidity inside? 
Not using any machines, but like Silica Gel Packets etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what may be causing the moisture? Why due to construction?

Comment: While building they pour water on walls to make them hard. Bricks and cement absorb it. And that's why its moist.